# Parallels - Changing screen resolution of Fedora 11 virtual machine?

Tags: parallels, fedora-11

I have a Fedora 11 vm installed on my osx machine and can't change the screen resolution higher than 1024x768. How can I raise the resolution?

I've tried adding additional Modes in xorg.conf and changed the depth from 24 to 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to increase the video card memory in the parallels configuration panel. It raised it from 3mb (default setting) to 32mb, which fixed the issue. The dynamic screen resolution feature also works (resolution changes on window resize).

Issue can be diagnosed in /var/log/Xorg.0.log (Error reported under Parallel Tools).